# openstack nova compute vm delete operation

Tags: openstack

We are trying to troubleshoot the stuck vm issue in openstack nova. sometimes when we try to delete VM, it gets in deleting state in DB and never get deleted from compute node.we are suspecting it has something to do with rabbitmq. My question is what actually happens in the backend when we give command '''nova delete '''. How the control plane services handle the request. how does rabbitmq handle the request. If any useful link is present to ans this, please provide the link.

Comment: Try to restart `nova-compute` and `nova-libvirt` in the vm's hypervisor, then check the vm's status.

Comment: i did try nova-compute restart but the effect is not always the same. some time it will clear the VM sometime it does not. the nova-libvirt service , i did not check. can you explain the use of nova-libvirt service .??

Comment: `Libvirt is the most commonly used virtualisation driver in OpenStack.`